# How to make a function/sub available to all forms in a project?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, function, methods

I have a sub that I want to be available to (or "callable from") **all** forms:

```
' Call some Sub from another form.     
someSub()
```

I'm having difficulty finding examples online thus my suspicion that the crux of my issue may be terminological.

## How?

Can anyone guide me as to what I should be looking at?:

- Global Sub
- Static Sub
- Shared Sub
- Private Sub

## Where?

Where should I position my "universal" sub?:

- Arbitrarily place it in one of the forms.
- Create a code file and somehow integrate into it each form?

Comment: declare it as public sub inside a Module

Comment: This works and it answers the how and where. May as well post it as the answer.

Comment: It would be useful to know why my question received a negative vote. Naturally, I'd like to avoid repeating whatever mistake the negative vote represents. Irrespective of how willing I am, I can't correct myself if the error on my part isn't presented to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

declare it as public Sub inside a Module

```
Public Module GlobalFunctions

Public Sub YourSub()

End Sub

End Module
```

hope this will help you

Answer (score 2):

Make it public.

Public Sub MySub()

Then you can call it from every form.

Myform.MySub()

Comment: Thanks. This works. I didn't realise methods can/should be referenced by prefixing the form name.

Comment: making sub public inside a form works but not logic and you should avoid

Comment: @HadiHassan I'm opting for the module approach as per your comment. It makes more to keep the function separate from all forms since it's not exclusively proprietary to any them.

Comment: @ClarusDignus i will post it as answer for others if they had same question